# Why this way of using fucntions arguments does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does this function print `arg1 arg2` instead of `Hello world`? Shouldn't arg be equal to the arguments arg1 and arg2 and then be used in `print()`?

```
def printer(arg1, arg2):
    for i in range(2):
        arg = 'arg{} '.format(str(i+1))
        print(arg, end="")

printer('Hello', 'world')
```

Comment: A string containing the name of a variable is not the variable. It "doesn't work" because it's wrong. That is to say, it works fine; it does exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: It's not at all clear that this is an appropriate duplicate.  OP is clearly interested in why Python doesn't recognize strings as symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `locals()` to access current local scope:

```
def printer(arg1, arg2):
    for i in range(2):
        arg = 'arg{}'.format(str(i+1))
        print(locals().get(arg), end="")

printer('Hello', 'world')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print strings, not your arguments. If you need to iterate through your function arguments, you can do something like this:

#### Code:

```
def printer(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg, end="")

printer('Hello', 'world')
```

#### Results:

```
Helloworld
```

Answer (score -1):

@kindle is right.  You're making a string variable. And Stephen Rauch's answer is the a better way to accomplish what you want.

However, Python can be made to evaluate a string as code using the `eval` function.  You *could* get the effect you expected by changing

```
print(arg, end="")
```

to

```
print(eval(arg), end="")
```